# Calculate number of negative values between two dates

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame of SPEI values. I want to calculate two statistics (explained below) at an interval of

1. 20 years i.e 2021-2040, 2041-2060, 2061-2080, 2081-2100. The first column contains the Date (month-year), and
2. Each year i.e. 2021, 2022, 2023 etc. till 2100.

The statistics are:

1. Drought frequency: Number of times SPEI < 0 in the specified period (20 years and 1 year respectively)
2. Drought Duration: Equal to the number of months between its start (included) and end month (not included) of the specified period. I am assuming a drought event starts when SPEI < 0.

I was wondering if there's a way to do that in R? It seems like an easy problem, but I don't know how to do it. Please help me out. Excel is taking too long. Thanks.

```
> head(test, 20)
         Date      spei-3
1  2021-01-01          NA
2  2021-02-01          NA
3  2021-03-01 -0.52133737
4  2021-04-01 -0.60047887
5  2021-05-01  0.56838399
6  2021-06-01  0.02285012
7  2021-07-01  0.26288462
8  2021-08-01 -0.14314685
9  2021-09-01 -0.73132256
10 2021-10-01 -1.23389220
11 2021-11-01 -1.15874943
12 2021-12-01  0.27954143
13 2022-01-01  1.14606657
14 2022-02-01  0.66872986
15 2022-03-01 -1.13758050
16 2022-04-01 -0.27861017
17 2022-05-01  0.99992395
18 2022-06-01  0.61024314
19 2022-07-01 -0.47450485
20 2022-08-01 -1.06682997
```

Edit: 
I very much like to add some code, but I don't know where to start.

```
test = "E:/drought.xlsx"
#Extract year and month and add it as a column
test$Year =  format(test$Date,"%Y")
test$Month = format(test$Date,"%B")
```

I don't know how to go from here. I found that `cumsum` can help, but how do I select one year and then apply `cumsum` on it. I am not withholding code on purpose. I just don't know where or how to begin.

Comment: There probably is BUT why you don't you try it first so that others can see your thinking.

Comment: You're likely to get more help if you post a reproducible example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and show us what you tried first. Have a look at the tidyverse package, I think that is a good place to start.

Comment: For date manipulations you should take a look at the package `lubridate`. Extract the year by using `year(drought_data$Date)` and the month by `month(drought_data$Date)`.

Comment: Please show the expected output corresponding to the input shown.

Comment: Hey! Thank you everyone for your help. @m.evans has answered it below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple questions the OP's post so I will go through them step by step. You'll need `dplyr` and `lubridate` for this workflow.

First, we create some fake data to use:

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)
#create example data
dd<- data.frame(Date = seq.Date(as.Date("2021-01-01"), as.Date("2100-12-01"), by = "month"),
                      spei = rnorm(960,0,2))
```

That will look like this, similar to what you have above

```
> head(dd)
        Date        spei year   year_20 drought
1 2021-01-01 -6.85689789 2021 2021_2040       1
2 2021-02-01 -0.09292459 2021 2021_2040       1
3 2021-03-01  0.13715922 2021 2021_2040       0
4 2021-04-01  2.26805601 2021 2021_2040       0
5 2021-05-01 -0.47325008 2021 2021_2040       1
6 2021-06-01  0.37034138 2021 2021_2040       0
```

Then we can use lubridate and cut to create our yearly and 20-year variables to group by later and create a column `drought` signifying if `spei` was negative.

```
#create a column to group on by year and by 20-year
dd <- dd %>%
  mutate(year  = year(Date),
         year_20 = cut(year, breaks = c(2020,2040,2060,2080, 2100), include.lowest = T,
                       labels = c("2021_2040", "2041_2060", "2061_2080", "2081_2100")))  %>%
  #column signifying if that month was a drought
  mutate(drought = ifelse(spei<0,1,0))
```

Once we have that, we just use the `group_by` function to get frequency (or number of months with a drought) by year or 20-year period

```
#by year
dd %>%
  group_by(year) %>%
  summarise(year_freq = sum(drought)) %>%
  ungroup()

# A tibble: 80 x 2
    year year_freq
   <dbl>     <dbl>
 1  2021         6
 2  2022         4
 3  2023         7
 4  2024         6
 5  2025         6
 6  2026         7

#by 20-year group
dd %>%
  group_by(year_20) %>%
  summarise(year20_freq = sum(drought)) %>%
  ungroup()

# A tibble: 4 x 2
  year_20   year20_freq
  <fct>           <dbl>
1 2021_2040         125
2 2041_2060         121
3 2061_2080         121
4 2081_2100         132
```

Calculating drought duration is a bit more complicated. It involves

1. identifying the first month of each drought
2. calculating the length of each drought
3. combining information from 1 and 2 together

We can use `lag` to identify when a month changed from "no drought" to "drought". In this case we want an index of where the value in row `i` is different from that in row `i-1`

```
# find index of where values change. 
change.ind <- dd$drought != lag(dd$drought)
#use index to find drought start
drought.start <- dd[change.ind & dd$drought == 1,]
```

This results in a subset of the initial dataset, but only with the rows with the first month of a drought. Then we can use `rle` to calculate the length of the drought. `rle` will calculate the length of every run of numbers, so we will have to subset to only those runs where the value==1 (drought)

```
#calculate drought lengths
drought.lengths <- rle(dd$drought)
# we only want droughts (values = 1)
drought.lengths <- drought.lengths$lengths[drought.lengths$values==1]
```

Now we can combine these two pieces of information together. The first row is an `NA` because there is no value at `i-1` to compare the lag to. It can be dropped, unless you want to include that data.

```
drought.dur <- cbind(drought.start, drought_length = drought.lengths)
head(drought.dur)
         Date        spei year   year_20 drought drought_length
NA       <NA>          NA   NA      <NA>      NA              2
5  2021-05-01 -0.47325008 2021 2021_2040       1              1
9  2021-09-01 -2.04564549 2021 2021_2040       1              1
11 2021-11-01 -1.04293866 2021 2021_2040       1              2
14 2022-02-01 -0.83759671 2022 2021_2040       1              1
17 2022-05-01 -0.07784316 2022 2021_2040       1              1
```